# PyCharm Error: Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)

Tags: python, pycharm

I keep having this error in PyCharm.

```
Backend WebAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)
```

Any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: The error comes from the process you're trying to run. You've provided zero information on what the process is. Therefore, there's zero chance that anyone could have ideas how to fix this.

Comment: Thank you Yole. it is a python script that I am trying to run from the python console   `exec(open('python1_updated.py').read())`

Comment: I have the same problem running Tensorflow hello world

Comment: We had the same issue, the same code works on Windows and does not work on the Mac M series. We just use windows due to the limited time...